# How long do I need the TURN servers

Tags: webrtc, p2p, stun, turn

If I have a TURN server which I use for my WebRTC application, do I have to rely on it for both

1. creating connection between two peers
2. sending data between these peers

or can I close the server once the connection has been established?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for most connections (~80%) the TURN server will only be used for a very short period. For any connection that can not use a peer-to-peer connection it will have to relay packets for the whole session so you can not close it.

Comment: I would love to see some data on that number (~80%)

Comment: see https://medium.com/the-making-of-appear-in/what-kind-of-turn-server-is-being-used-d67dbfc2ff5d

Comment: Very interesting read Phillip! We've done some work at Peer5 regarding connectivity (we don't use TURN) and if I recall correctly this number varies _greatly_ by connection type, ISP and other network architecture. It would be interesting to look at these numbers with TURN (which we don't use).